# Lightweight & easy to use 2D animation software?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, animation

Does someone knows a lightweight and easy to use 2D animacion software (for Win [XP])? I need something easy to use because it's for 10-11yo kids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few listed on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Free_2D_graphics_animation_software).  I can't recommend any personally, but I've heard [Pencil](http://www.pencil-animation.org/) mentioned previously.